# numpy efficient way of calculating diagonal subtractions without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, linear-gradients

I have the below 2d `numpy` array:

```
array([[5, 2, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 12, 3]])
```

I have a (gradient) equation that uses diagonals to perform a calculation like below:

```
(array[i , j] - array[i + 1, j + 1]) **2 + (array[i+1 , j] - array[i, j + 1]) **2
```

The equation is very simple. It is getting each  2x2 sub matrix, subtracting the diagonals, squaring them and then adding each result. In the example used above for the first 2x2 matrix the equation would yield:

```
(5 - 5) ^ 2 + (4 - 2) ^ 2 = 4
```

This value would then be the first element a new `numpy` array. And the rest of the elements would be populated the same way by moving on to the next 2x2 submatrix.

The first obvious solution to this is to use a nested for loop over all rows and columns. But is there a more efficient way using `numpy` (or other libraries) to avoid the for loops. Or if not avoiding the for loops directly, making the calculation more efficient for larger 2D arrays.

Comment: What happens on the boundary conditions? For example, what is the expected result for the last line?

Comment: boundary is not calculated.. If I had a loop it would stop at the second to last row / column

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ideas:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
from numba import njit, prange


arr0 = np.array(
    [[5, 2, 6],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 12, 3]])

np.random.seed(0)
arr1 = np.random.randint(0, 20, (20, 20))

def weird_quazi_det_op(arr):
    H, W = arr.shape
    out_arr = np.zeros((H-1, W-1))
    for h in prange(H-1):
        for w in prange(W-1):
            out_arr[h, w] = (arr[h, w] - arr[h+1, w+1])**2 + (arr[h+1, w] - arr[h, w+1])**2
    return out_arr


@njit(parallel=True)
def weird_quazi_det_patallel(arr):
    H, W = arr.shape
    out_arr = np.zeros((H-1, W-1))
    for h in prange(H-1):
        for w in prange(W-1):
            out_arr[h, w] = (arr[h, w] - arr[h+1, w+1])**2 + (arr[h+1, w] - arr[h, w+1])**2
    return out_arr

@njit(fastmath=True)
def weird_quazi_det_fastmath(arr):
    H, W = arr.shape
    out_arr = np.zeros((H-1, W-1))
    for h in prange(H-1):
        for w in prange(W-1):
            out_arr[h, w] = (arr[h, w] - arr[h+1, w+1])**2 + (arr[h+1, w] - arr[h, w+1])**2
    return out_arr


def weird_quazi_det_conv(arr):
    sub0kern = np.array([[1, 0,], [0, -1]])
    sub1kern = np.array([[0, -1,], [1, 0]])

    sub0arr = convolve2d(arr, sub0kern, mode = 'valid')
    sub1arr = convolve2d(arr, sub1kern, mode = 'valid')

    out_arr = sub0arr**2+sub1arr**2
    return out_arr

# init runs
weird_quazi_det_patallel(arr0)
weird_quazi_det_fastmath(arr0)




print('===== op example: =====')
print(' - op code:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_op(arr0)
print(' - op code + parallel:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_patallel(arr0)
print(' - op code + fastmath:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_fastmath(arr0)
print(' - conv solution:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_conv(arr0)

print('===== larger example: =====')
print(' - op code:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_op(arr1)
print(' - op code + parallel:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_patallel(arr1)
print(' - op code + fastmath:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_fastmath(arr1)
print(' - conv solution:')
%timeit weird_quazi_det_conv(arr1)
```

output:

```
===== op example: =====
 - op code:
The slowest run took 6.15 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 10.6 µs per loop
 - op code + parallel:
The slowest run took 251.69 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 5.71 µs per loop
 - op code + fastmath:
The slowest run took 32.22 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 5: 678 ns per loop
 - conv solution:
The slowest run took 6.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 18.7 µs per loop
===== larger example: =====
 - op code:
1000 loops, best of 5: 714 µs per loop
 - op code + parallel:
The slowest run took 180.35 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 6.33 µs per loop
 - op code + fastmath:
The slowest run took 14.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 5: 1.42 µs per loop
 - conv solution:
10000 loops, best of 5: 41 µs per loop
```

I thought using convolutions to perform the local diagonal subtractions and then summing the differences will be the fastest solution, but it seems there's no beating the speed of numba's compiled code for me, even using the simplest implementation.

Comment: Note you can specify the types to the Numba function or run it once before so not to pay the cost of the compilation time during the fist run. Besides, using a double prange is certainly a bad idea since it may cause nested parallelism which is known to results in bad performance. Note also that creating threads introduce a significant overhead for small arrays. Thus, a parallel version may not be the best regarding the target input array. You could also try to use `fastmath=True` to check if it is faster for the Numba function (assuming there is no NaN values).

Comment: tried this after install numba `pip install numba` but there is a warning saying `NumbaWarning: The TBB threading layer requires TBB version 2021 update 1 or later i.e., TBB_INTERFACE_VERSION >= 12010. Found TBB_INTERFACE_VERSION = 11008. The TBB threading layer is disabled.
  warnings.warn(problem)`. Also tried to upgrade tbb but same warning occured.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, you're right, i got 5-10 times speed up using fastmath instead of parallel. ty for the edit.